# Post subscription process in transactional replication sql server

Tags: transactional-replication

I'm using PULL subscription method in Transactional Replication (SQL SERVER 2012).
Distributor is in different server and topology looks like:
Server A(Publisher)-> Server B(Distributor)-> Server C(Subscriber).

Publisher/Subscription jobs completed successfully (55Gb data) and table values match.
In process, snapshot (bcp) files where copied in Server B (distributor).
Later, into Server C (subscriber) D drive "Replication" directory.

After successful replication, I looked into "Replication" directory (only directory in D drive) in Server C, it is empty , but D drive shows around 55Gb full.

I'd like to know what happens to files in Server C (subscriber) after Subscription completes successfully.
Also, is there a process to be configured to delete bcp files from Subscriber or it removes files automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed that, right after availability of bcp files in Distrubutor, subscriber pulls data and applies it to subscriber database within no time, thus leaving no trace in subscriber.

As of now, I wait 10 minutes after snapshot agent succeeds, and then, reconcile between publisher and subscriber and data match.